# Missing ROM files when building linux-on-litex

Tags: linux, fpga, lattice

To get familiar with my Lattice ECP5-evn and the LiteX toolchain I am trying to build [linux-on-litex](https://github.com/litex-hub/linux-on-litex-vexriscv). But already in the simulation I'm running into trouble. I'm using virtual box with the latest ubuntu image (ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64).

I installed the prerequisites and on top of that ninja-build, default-jdk and stb. Then I installed LiteX and downloaded the following RISC-V toolchain: riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc-8.1.0-2019.01.0-x86_64-linux-ubuntu14. Then I cloned the linux-on-litex repo and ran `./sim.py`. Everything is set correctly in my PATH variable and I'm getting no errors there.

However, the simulation is complaining about missing images. And indeed, according to the boot.json which is provided there should be 4 files there:

- Image
- rv32.dtb
- rootfs.cpio
- opensbi.bin

However, none of the files come with the git repo, so I guess I need to compile/collect them myself. I noticed that only  rv32.dtb is created when running `./sim.py`. Perhaps the other 3 files should also be created automatically. But I'm getting no errors there, only that the files are missing. Here is the terminal output of running `./sim.py`:

```
INFO:SoC:        __   _ __      _  __  
INFO:SoC:       / /  (_) /____ | |/_/  
INFO:SoC:      / /__/ / __/ -_)>  <    
INFO:SoC:     /____/_/\__/\__/_/|_|  
INFO:SoC:  Build your hardware, easily!
INFO:SoC:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO:SoC:Creating SoC... (2022-01-12 23:25:20)
INFO:SoC:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO:SoC:FPGA device : SIM.
INFO:SoC:System clock: 100.000MHz.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:Creating Bus Handler...
INFO:SoCBusHandler:32-bit wishbone Bus, 4.0GiB Address Space.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:Adding reserved Bus Regions...
INFO:SoCBusHandler:Bus Handler created.
INFO:SoCCSRHandler:Creating CSR Handler...
INFO:SoCCSRHandler:32-bit CSR Bus, 32-bit Aligned, 16.0KiB Address Space, 2048B Paging, big Ordering (Up to 32 Locations).
INFO:SoCCSRHandler:Adding reserved CSRs...
INFO:SoCCSRHandler:ctrl CSR added at Location 0.
INFO:SoCCSRHandler:uart CSR added at Location 2.
INFO:SoCCSRHandler:timer0 CSR added at Location 3.
INFO:SoCCSRHandler:CSR Handler created.
INFO:SoCIRQHandler:Creating IRQ Handler...
INFO:SoCIRQHandler:IRQ Handler (up to 32 Locations).
INFO:SoCIRQHandler:Adding reserved IRQs...
INFO:SoCIRQHandler:IRQ Handler created.
INFO:SoC:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO:SoC:Initial SoC:
INFO:SoC:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO:SoC:32-bit wishbone Bus, 4.0GiB Address Space.
INFO:SoC:32-bit CSR Bus, 32-bit Aligned, 16.0KiB Address Space, 2048B Paging, big Ordering (Up to 32 Locations).
CSR Locations: (3)
- ctrl   : 0
- uart   : 2
- timer0 : 3
INFO:SoC:IRQ Handler (up to 32 Locations).
INFO:SoC:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO:SoCBusHandler:io0 Region added at Origin: 0x80000000, Size: 0x80000000, Mode: RW, Cached: False Linker: False.
INFO:SoC:CPU overriding rom mapping from 0x00000000 to 0x00000000.
INFO:SoC:CPU overriding sram mapping from 0x01000000 to 0x10000000.
INFO:SoC:CPU overriding main_ram mapping from 0x40000000 to 0x40000000.
INFO:SoC:CPU overriding csr mapping from 0xf0000000 to 0xf0000000.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:cpu_bus0 added as Bus Master.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:plic Region added at Origin: 0xf0c00000, Size: 0x00400000, Mode: RW, Cached: False Linker: False.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:plic added as Bus Slave.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:clint Region added at Origin: 0xf0010000, Size: 0x00010000, Mode: RW, Cached: False Linker: False.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:clint added as Bus Slave.
INFO:SoCIRQHandler:uart IRQ added at Location 0.
INFO:SoCIRQHandler:timer0 IRQ added at Location 1.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:rom Region added at Origin: 0x00000000, Size: 0x00008000, Mode: R, Cached: True Linker: False.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:rom added as Bus Slave.
INFO:SoC:RAM rom added Origin: 0x00000000, Size: 0x00008000, Mode: R, Cached: True Linker: False.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:sram Region added at Origin: 0x10000000, Size: 0x00002000, Mode: RW, Cached: True Linker: False.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:sram added as Bus Slave.
INFO:SoC:RAM sram added Origin: 0x10000000, Size: 0x00002000, Mode: RW, Cached: True Linker: False.
INFO:SoCIRQHandler:uart IRQ added at Location 0.
INFO:SoCIRQHandler:timer0 IRQ added at Location 1.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:opensbi Region added at Origin: 0x40f00000, Size: 0x00080000, Mode: RW, Cached: True Linker: True.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:main_ram Region added at Origin: 0x40000000, Size: 0x04000000, Mode: RW, Cached: True Linker: False.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:main_ram added as Bus Slave.
VexRiscv cluster : VexRiscvLitexSmpCluster_Cc1_Iw32Is4096Iy1_Dw32Ds4096Dy1_ITs4DTs4_Ldw32_Ood
INFO:SoCBusHandler:csr Region added at Origin: 0xf0000000, Size: 0x00010000, Mode: RW, Cached: False Linker: False.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:csr added as Bus Slave.
INFO:SoCCSRHandler:bridge added as CSR Master.
INFO:SoCBusHandler:Interconnect: InterconnectShared (1 <-> 6).
INFO:SoCCSRHandler:sdram CSR allocated at Location 1.
INFO:SoCCSRHandler:supervisor CSR allocated at Location 4.
INFO:SoC:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO:SoC:Finalized SoC:
INFO:SoC:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO:SoC:32-bit wishbone Bus, 4.0GiB Address Space.
IO Regions: (1)
io0                 : Origin: 0x80000000, Size: 0x80000000, Mode: RW, Cached: False Linker: False
Bus Regions: (7)
rom                 : Origin: 0x00000000, Size: 0x00008000, Mode: R, Cached: True Linker: False
sram                : Origin: 0x10000000, Size: 0x00002000, Mode: RW, Cached: True Linker: False
main_ram            : Origin: 0x40000000, Size: 0x04000000, Mode: RW, Cached: True Linker: False
opensbi             : Origin: 0x40f00000, Size: 0x00080000, Mode: RW, Cached: True Linker: True
csr                 : Origin: 0xf0000000, Size: 0x00010000, Mode: RW, Cached: False Linker: False
clint               : Origin: 0xf0010000, Size: 0x00010000, Mode: RW, Cached: False Linker: False
plic                : Origin: 0xf0c00000, Size: 0x00400000, Mode: RW, Cached: False Linker: False
Bus Masters: (1)
- cpu_bus0
Bus Slaves: (6)
- plic
- clint
- rom
- sram
- main_ram
- csr
INFO:SoC:32-bit CSR Bus, 32-bit Aligned, 16.0KiB Address Space, 2048B Paging, big Ordering (Up to 32 Locations).
CSR Locations: (5)
- ctrl       : 0
- sdram      : 1
- uart       : 2
- timer0     : 3
- supervisor : 4
INFO:SoC:IRQ Handler (up to 32 Locations).
IRQ Locations: (2)
- uart   : 0
- timer0 : 1
INFO:SoC:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
make: Entering directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/libc'
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make: Leaving directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/libc'
make: Entering directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/libcompiler_rt'
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make: Leaving directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/libcompiler_rt'
make: Entering directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/libbase'
 CC       console.o
 CC       system.o
 CC       memtest.o
 CC       uart.o
 CC       spiflash.o
 CC       i2c.o
 AR       libbase.a
make: Leaving directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/libbase'
make: Entering directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/libfatfs'
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make: Leaving directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/libfatfs'
make: Entering directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/liblitespi'
 CC       spiflash.o
 AR       liblitespi.a
make: Leaving directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/liblitespi'
make: Entering directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/liblitedram'
 CC       sdram.o
 CC       bist.o
 CC       sdram_dbg.o
 AR       liblitedram.a
make: Leaving directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/liblitedram'
make: Entering directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/libliteeth'
 CC       udp.o
 CC       mdio.o
 AR       libliteeth.a
make: Leaving directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/libliteeth'
make: Entering directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/liblitesdcard'
 CC       sdcard.o
 CC       spisdcard.o
 AR       liblitesdcard.a
make: Leaving directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/liblitesdcard'
make: Entering directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/liblitesata'
 CC       sata.o
 AR       liblitesata.a
make: Leaving directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/liblitesata'
make: Entering directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/bios'
 CC       isr.o
 CC       boot.o
 CC       cmd_bios.o
 CC       cmd_mem.o
 CC       cmd_boot.o
 CC       cmd_i2c.o
 CC       cmd_spiflash.o
 CC       cmd_litedram.o
 CC       cmd_liteeth.o
 CC       cmd_litesdcard.o
 CC       cmd_litesata.o
 CC       sim_debug.o
 CC       main.o
 CC       bios.elf
chmod -x bios.elf
 OBJCOPY  bios.bin
chmod -x bios.bin
python3 -m litex.soc.software.mkmscimg bios.bin --little
python3 -m litex.soc.software.memusage bios.elf /home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/bios/../include/generated/regions.ld riscv64-unknown-elf
readelf: Warning: Bogus end-of-siblings marker detected at offset 4c in .debug_info section
readelf: Warning: Bogus end-of-siblings marker detected at offset 4d in .debug_info section
readelf: Warning: DIE at offset 0x4e refers to abbreviation number 3 which does not exist

ROM usage: 20.36KiB     (63.62%)
RAM usage: 1.36KiB  (16.99%)

make: Leaving directory '/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/bios'
>>>/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/bios/bios.bin<<<
>>>/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/build/sim/software/bios/bios.bin<<<
INFO:SoC:Initializing ROM rom with contents (Size: 0x5180).
INFO:SoC:Auto-Resizing ROM rom from 0x8000 to 0x5180.
>>>images/Image<<<
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sim.py", line 230, in <module>
    main()
  File "./sim.py", line 202, in main
    soc = SoCLinux( i!=0,
  File "./sim.py", line 105, in __init__
    ram_init = get_mem_data({
  File "/home/anteino/shared_work/litex/litex/litex/soc/integration/common.py", line 46, in get_mem_data
    raise OSError(f"Unable to find {filename} memory content file.")
OSError: Unable to find images/Image memory content file.
```

I tried searching the LiteX wiki and using google but I cannot find a solution and I have also not figured out one myself. Can somebody who has experience with LiteX please assist me?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/litex-hub/linux-on-litex-vexriscv/issues/164
You can get prebuilt bitstream here, just put them on images directory

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I finally gave up on this project. Every step of the way was a big pain...